# Go string format fill only part of the arguments

Tags: go

I have a standard string format for calling an external api. e.g. `https://%s?client=%s&password=%s`.

Here is the first %s endpoint of the request which depends on the business logic. While I can always determine the client and password in advance.

```
func getApiUrl(clientId int) string {
    urlFormat := "https://%s?client=%s&password=%s"
    clientname, clientpass := getByClientId(clientId)
    return fmt.Sprintf(urlFormat, _, clientname, clientpass) // https://%s?client=clientname&password=clientpass
}
```

I would like to write something like a function that will fill in some of the parameters. In this form, it does not work, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `"%s"` in the placeholder.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func getByClientId(clientId int) (string, string) {
    return "user", "password"
}

func getApiUrl(clientId int) string {
    urlFormat := "https://%s?client=%s&password=%s"
    clientname, clientpass := getByClientId(clientId)
    return fmt.Sprintf(urlFormat, "%s", clientname, clientpass) // https://%s?client=clientname&password=clientpass
}

func main() {
    userPasswordFilled := getApiUrl(3)
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf(userPasswordFilled, "example.com"))
}
```

[Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/kSkqNx3VCny)